# How to filter product collection using 2 or more category filters in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, collection

How to filter product collection using more than two category. In magento1, we can use `->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>'36,37'));` but how can i do this in magento2? Also i have checked Multiple category filter extension. Collection show correct but other filters (Like Price,color) and collection size and pagination give a wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

Add this categories filter

> $catalog_ids = array('10','20');
>
> $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));

Or use below full product collection with categories filter

> public function __construct(
>     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
>   $collectionFactory ) {    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
>   }
>
> $catalog_ids = array('10','20');
>
> $collection => $this->collectionFactory->create();
>
> $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
>
> $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));

I hope this might help you.

Thanks

Comment: Same code i used but  pagination and total product and price filter show wrong data.